# CKEditor: How can I automatically add a paragraf format to ordered lists?

Tags: drupal-7, html-lists, ckeditor

How can I make CKEditor automatically add a paragraf format to the `<li>` when an `<ol>` or `<ul>` is created?

Or can I make it add automatically a `<span>`, like:

```
<ol>

  <li> <span> text </span> </li>

  <li> <span> text </span> </li>

</ol>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to have it done on-line when typing/creating lists or when reading editor contents before saving to database?

Comment: I want to have it done when i create lists using ckeditor.

Comment: you can certainly do it after the fact with jQuery.